# Unexpected behavior with open() and numpy.savetext() functions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

## Problem

I am trying to output statistics about a table, followed by more table data using Pandas and numpy.

When I execute the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv(r'c:\Documents\DS\CAStateBuildingMetrics.csv')

waterUsage = data["Water Use (All Water Sources) (kgal)"]
dept = data[["Department Name", "Property Id"]]
mean = str(waterUsage.mean())
median = str(waterUsage.median())
most = str(waterUsage.mode())

hw1 = open(r'c:\Documents\DS\testFile', "a")
hw1.write("Mean Water Usage     Median Water Usage      Most Common Usage Amounts\n")
hw1.write(mean+'       '+median+'                   '+most)
np.savetxt(r'c:\Documents\DS\testFile', dept.values, fmt='%s')
```

The table output by np.savetext is written into `c:\Documents\DS\testFile` before the statistics about Mean, Median, and Mode water usage are written into the file. Below is the output I am describing:

Here is a sample of the table output, which ends up to be 1700 rows.

> Capitol Area Development Authority 1259182
>   Capitol Area Development Authority 1259200
>   Capitol Area Development Authority 1259218
>   California Department of Forestry and Fire Protection 3939905
>   California Department of Forestry and Fire Protection 3939906
>   California Department of Forestry and Fire Protection 3939907

After this, the script outputs the statistics in this format

> Mean Water Usage               Median Water Usage          Most Common Usage Amounts
>   6913.1633414932685                    182.35                                        0   165.0
>   Type: float64

## Question

How do I adjust the behavior to guarantee that the statistics appear before the table?

Comment: Pass `hw1` to `savetxt` instead of the filename.  That way it writes to the same open file.  And close it after.

Comment: That solution worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, as pointed out by @hpaulj, is that the same open file is not being referenced.

Replacing

```
np.savetxt(r'c:\Documents\DS\testFile', dept.values, fmt='%s')
```

With

```
np.savetxt(hw1, dept.values, fmt='%s')
hw1.close()
```

Will write all information in the expected order in the same file. [Closing it](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_close.htm) follows best practices of handling files in Python.